# Не запускаются sh скрипты из Nautilus

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня перестали запускаться sh скрипты двойным нажатием в файловом менеджере ubuntu nautilus.

Все разрешения, вроде, стоят.

В настройках nautilus - поведение - исполняемые текстовые файлы, стоит опция "Каждый раз спрашивать". По двойному клику окошко появляется (запустить, запустить в консоли и т. д.), но ничего не происходит далее.

Comment: а что в файле? на любой скрипт такая проблема?

Comment: запустите наутилус из командной строки, чтобы он в консоль ругался, чтобы ему не нравиться, может и напишет в чём дело

Comment: @PavelGridin странно, но если запускать nautilus из консоли, то скрипт срабатывает

Comment: @AndreyMihalev `#!/bin/bash

java -jar TestFX.jar` я попробовал написать другой скриптик `#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal`  он исполнился, но не открылся терминал, который должен открываться при запуске скрипта... то есть если я напишу echo '...' а затем gnome-terminal то просто откроется один терминал. Если исполнять этот скрипт из терминала, то в этой консоли выведется надпись из echo и откроется новый терминал как и должно происходить.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev То есть скрипт выполняется но потом сразу закрывает терминал? Тогда логично почему gui приложение кажется что не запускается

Comment: @AndreyMihalev хотя нет, я поставил в терминале опцию "При выходе из команды: Держать терминал открытым" и на мой скрипт он выдаёт ошибку что команда java не найдена. Хотя когда я из терминала выполняю java, то всё работает. Может и всё-таки я что-то не дописал в path? Я делал по этой инструкции: https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml Надо что-то ещё?

Answer (score 1):

В Наутилусе переставили значение по умолчанию для запуска приложений. Откройте параметры и переставьте флажок на запустить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также стоит проверить другие условия запуска(которые были и раньше)

Права на запуск:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установить можно `chmod +x file.sh`. А файловая система должна поддерживать разрешения запуска. На FAT и NTFS раньше спрашивало всегда, сейчас надо посмотреть... но по правильному запускаться ничего не должно.

Дальше проверь интерпретатор в первой строчке файла. Должно быть с полным путем `#!/bin/sh`. sh или bash для скриптов на шеле.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перед тем как я написал вопрос, стояла опция на варианте "Запустить". Не запускалось. Я поставил на "Спрашивать что делать" и пробовал все варианты из предложенных этой опцией. Не запускается. Всё, что можно было сделать основываясь на поиске в гугле по запросу: открывать sh двойным кликом, я попробовал. Месяц назад такой проблемы не было, возможно с очередным обновлением системы какая-нибудь настройка слетела, но инфы мало по этому поводу. Потому я и написал сюда.

Comment: В свойствах файла стоит разрешение на запуск ? Chmod +x? Шебанг стоит? Сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Разрешение на выполнение как программы стоит, а путь до bash тоже верен. `chmod +x file.sh` ничего не изменило. Я попробовал запустить nautilus из терминала и скрипт исполнился без проблем. Но если запускать nautilus из списка приложений, то скрипты не запускаются...